# Load testing eJabberd with Tsung on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ejabberd, tsung

I have Tsung loaded on one EC2 instance, i also have another EC2 instance with eJabberd. I want to load test eJabberd with Tsung.All ports and security groups are configure to all inbound, and all outbound.
Error that i get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx: Name or service not known
```

For reference my Tsung configuration:

```
    <clients>
       <client host="ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" use_controller_vm="true" maxusers="15000"></client>
    </clients>

    <servers>
     <server host="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="5222" type="tcp"></server>
    </servers>

  <load>
      <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="10" unit="minute">
       <users maxnumber="15000" interarrival="0.04" unit="second"></users>
      </arrivalphase>
     </load>


  <options>
     <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="15000"></option>
     <option type="ts_jabber" name="userid_max" value="15000"></option>
     <option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="http://www.ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"></option>
     <option type="ts_jabber" name="username" value=""></option>
     <option type="ts_jabber" name="passwd" value="test"></option>
    </options>

  <sessions> 
  <session probability="100" name="jabber-example" type="ts_jabber">
    <request><jabber type="connect" ack="local"></jabber></request>
    <thinktime value="2"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="authenticate">
      <request> <jabber type="auth_get" ack="local"></jabber></request>
      <request> <jabber type="auth_set_plain" ack="local"></jabber></request>
    </transaction>

    <request><jabber type="presence:initial" ack="global"></jabber></request>
    <thinktime value="600"></thinktime> 

    <transaction name="close">
      <request> <jabber type="close" ack="local"></jabber></request>
    </transaction>
  </session>
   </sessions>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case, set client host to 'localhost':

```
<client host="localhost" ...
```

If you have more tsung installed machines, they are connected via ssh. So check connectivity with ssh from the shell.

If you read http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-client-server.html and http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/faq.html , you'll get useful information.